# What affects the matchmaking?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When you search for a village to attack, how does Clash of Clans choose an enemy village?
Does it only choose villages by people with a similar amount of trophies, who are in the same league, does the town hall level also matter or is there anything else that influences the matchmaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the "[Raids](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids)" page on the wiki:

> Matchmaking matches you with another player based on your Trophies

This means usually you battle somebody in the same league, as your league is defined by how many trophies you have.

There are no other factors that effect matchmaking, including town hall level and experience level.

Answer (score 3):

With the new Clash of Clans update, the matchmaking algorithm will now try its best to match the player with the same TH level. The Trophies amount is weighted more than the TH level so if there is no player with the TH level within a limit of trophy difference, the algorithm will match you to a player of a different TH level.